# Is it possible to do OAuth2 Authentication with Username & Password only with Marketo?

Tags: marketo

Is it possible to do OAuth2 authentication like facebook/ google login, which only requires users to enter their username & password, without providing their client_id & client_secret?

The steps displayed here require the user to provide his client_id & client_secret for authentication.
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Marketo platform does not offer OAuth2 authentication similar to Facebook login or Google login.

Here is how the Marketo authentication process currently works for the REST API. A [Marketo custom service must first be created](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/quick-start-guide-for-marketo-rest-api/). Once a custom service is created, you will have access to a client id and client secret. You will use the client id and client secret to [generate an access token via the REST API authentication endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/). You will then use this access token to make subsequent requests to the REST API, such as to query lead data.

Comment: Can you share the client ID + secret for your platform and have customers provide Munchkin ID, or must customers provide client ID & Secret, too?